# Duplicate Resoure Error on JBoss 6

Tags: jboss

During the deployment of a JBoss 6 server i'm having a **duplicate resource error** as follows:

> Operation ("add") failed - address: ([("deployment" =>
>   "application.jar")]) - failure description: "JBAS014803: Duplicate
>   resource [(\"deployment\" => \"application.jar\")]"

When i look the folder `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/deployments` I can't see the duplicated war or anything like that.

Any clue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should check if the `$JBOSS_HOME/standalone/configuration/standalone.xml` doesn't have a duplicated `<deployment-scanner/>` entry that points to the same path.
Had the same issue and deleting one of those did the trick.